# Table with list of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I'm trying to put together a table with seven columns for a schedule. On each column I want to list twenty fields. I playing around but I cannot find the way to make it work.

Controller:

```
def new
  @doctor = Doctor.new

  140.times { @doctor.schedules.build }
end
```

Model:

```
has_many :schedules

def schedule_attributes=(schedule_attributes)
    schedule_attributes.each do |attributes|
      schedules.build(attributes)
    end
end
```

Form:

```
<tr>
  <% @doctor.schedules.each_with_index do |schedule, i| %>
    <td>
      <% if i > 0 && i % 20 == 0 %>
      </td>
      <td>
      <% end %>
      <%= fields_for "doctor[schedule_attributes][]", schedule do |schedule_form|  %>
        <ul>
           <% schedule_form.text_field :day, value: @days[0] %>
           <li><%= schedule_form.check_box :hour, value: "8:00" %></li>
        </ul>                 
      <% end %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

This only outputs forty fields. The idea is output 140 fields, twenty in each column.

I would like to insert the twenty fields in one single cell. Can somebody point me on the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple (quick and dirty) approach, you can do this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <% @doctor.schedules.limit(140).each_with_index do |schedule, i| %>
      <% if i > 0 && i % 20 == 0 %>
        </td>
        <td>          
      <% end %>
      <%= fields_for "doctor[schedule_attributes][]", schedule do |schedule_form|  %>
        <ul>
           <% schedule_form.text_field :day, value: @days[0] %>
           <li><%= schedule_form.check_box :hour, value: "8:00" %></li>
        </ul>                 
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you want to reuse this logic, a helper method should be used:

```
def to_columns(collection, num_columns)
  html = ""
  count = collection.size
  num_rows = (count / num_columns.to_f).ceil
  collection.each_with_index do |item, i|        
    html << '<td>'.html_safe if (i % num_rows == 0)
    html << yield(item, i)
    html << '</td>'.html_safe if (i % num_rows == 0 || i == (count - 1))
  end
  html
end
```

And in your view, let this method make your `<td>` tags as needed:

```
<tr>
  <%= to_columns(@doctor.schedules.limit(140), 7) do |schedule, i| %>
    <%= fields_for "doctor[schedule_attributes][]", schedule do |schedule_form|  %>
      <ul>
         <% schedule_form.text_field :day, value: @days[0] %>
         <li><%= schedule_form.check_box :hour, value: "8:00" %></li>
      </ul>                 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, but it adds the fields in a horizontal way.
What I'm trying to accomplish is:

Monday     Tuesday       ...
f1         f21           ...
f3         f22           ...
...        ...           ...
f20        f40

Comment: @user1907273: Right, I just noticed that - fixed

Comment: Ok, does that not do what you needed?

Comment: No, I tried the helper method but it does not print any fields.

in the controller I set 140.times, do I have to set the limit however?

Comment: Calling `.build` doesn't add a schedule to your `@doctor.schedules` collection.  It simply creates a new schedule object for you to use (which you aren't).  You can get around this in your case by calling: `140.times{ @doctor.schedules += @doctor.schedules.build }`

Comment: I get this if I try that approach: can't convert Schedule to Array (Schedule#to_ary gives NilClass)

Comment: hmm, try this then: `@doctor.schedules = (1..140).to_a.map{ @doctor.schedules.build }`

Comment: Controller
https://github.com/jmercedes/doc/blob/master/app/controllers/doctors_controller.rb

Model
https://github.com/jmercedes/doc/blob/master/app/models/doctor.rb

Form
https://github.com/jmercedes/doc/blob/master/app/views/doctors/_form.html.erb

Helper
https://github.com/jmercedes/doc/blob/master/app/helpers/doctors_helper.rb